# washing machine trap

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

How far can the trap be from the washing machine? The trap now is about five feet from the waste line and the machine is next to it. I want to move the machine 10 feet from the trap, but don't want to relocate the trap. Is that OK?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's documentation for the washer, as it might have restrictions. Also check local plumbing codes for trap arm length.

Comment: For code, you would need a 4" pipe size for a maximum of 16'  Are you looking for opinions on a non-code option?

Comment: Can you provide a photo?

Comment: Consider running the drain hose with a high point in the middle of the run between the machine and the trap, so that when the machine's pump stops you won't have an entire hose-full of water draining back into the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Typically washers discharge into a standpipe, which extends 18"-42" above the trap weir. The plumbing can then continue on 5'-8' before there's a vent (5' for 1¼" pipe, 6' for 1½" pipe, 8' for 2" pipe).

References:

- IRC Table P3105.1
- IRC P2706.2